# Hide a Column from ColumnChooser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, visual-c#-express-2010, devexpress-windows-ui

Currently I'm developing an application with devexpress, and I had set two columns to hide like this:

```
gridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
```

However, when I run my program, there is an option from the DataGrid called "Selector de Columnas" (in English ColumnChooser). In this option the two columns that I set to be hidden are shown. I don't want the user to see these columns but I still need them, so I just want to hide them.

[image: You can see the problem here]

I searched in the online documentation from Devexpress and they state [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6154) that columns can be hidden with the [ShowInColumnChooser](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_ShowInColumnChoosertopic) property. However I'm not able to hide these columns in the ColumnChooser. They don't show you any example, just this line of code:

```
public bool ShowInColumnChooser { get; set; }
```

I guess this is a property from some Devexpress control, however they don't state how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the links you referred to are related to the WPF [DXGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/), but as far as I can see from your screenshot, you are working with the [XtraGrid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGrid) (WinForms). If so, you should use the [OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_ShowInCustomizationFormtopic) property as follows:

```
column1.OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;
```

Related help articles:
[Column and Card Field Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument638)
[Customization Form](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument555)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a specific column from being showed/hidden, set the column's properties `OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm` and `OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide` to `false`.